# Accessing ChatGPT API Key Securely for Public Website

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, openai-api, api-key

I have made a website that uses the ChatGPT API - but I am struggling to figure out how to securely use my API key without exposing it to the public. So far I have tried using AWS Lambda (and AWS Secrets Manager) in order to securely retrieve my API key. Below is the progress I have made thus far, and the current issues I am running into. Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

**Accomplished**

- The code for the website is currently working if I hard-code my API key in the code. The current website is just made using basic HTML/CSS/JS (No React, etc.)
- My AWS Lambda function is able to return a JSON object in the format of "Key: value"

**Issues (and what I have tried)**

- I have not been successful in being able to invoke/call my AWS Lambda function. I have tried using code from a mix of tutorials, guides, and ChatGPT (code I am currently using in an .msj file and trying to import it to my .js file) but nothing has worked.
- Errors I have received:

1. Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
2. Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at reverse_dictionary_JS.js:1:1)

**Solutions?**
At this point I had a few ideas to solve this problem but would like to get some guidance from anyone that can help.

Code I am currently using to invoke AWS Lambda function:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk'); 

AWS.config.update({ region: 'us-east-1' }); 

const lambda = new AWS.Lambda();
const params = { FunctionName: 'ChatGPT_API_KEY_lambda', Payload: JSON.stringify({ key: 'value' }) };

lambda.invoke(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err, err.stack);
    } else {
        console.log(data); // Log the response from the Lambda function
        // Handle the response data here 
    }
});

function LambdaFunction() {
    lambda.invoke(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) { 
            console.error(err, err.stack);
        } else {
            console.log(data); // Log the response from the Lambda function
            
            // Handle the response data here         
        }
    })
};
```

I expected to be able to call my AWS Lambda function, parse the response into my apiKey variable and run my code from there

Comment: *securely use my API key without exposing it to the public* - make all requests via your server, because if the browser can make the request directly, it has to use the API key, which exposes the API key

Comment: You should make your own API using API Gateway into Lambda or through some other server solution. Your api will have the feature you want and communicate with GPT using your key and never expose it to the client. Then you can implement whatever authentication strategy you'd like to keep your front end from being able to abuse your custom api